# Mongo Node JS is behaving differently on a 2nd AWS ECS instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a NodeJS server, along with MongoDB, running on an AWS EC2 instance. I have replicated this instance and started up another one, but the behavior of the code is now different. What I mean by behavior is the following: I am using NodeJS async library and I have the following code snippet:

```
async.waterfall([
function(cb) {
    db.collection.remove(query, cb);
},
function(result, cb) {
    func_foo(result, cb);
},
...
```

on the new instance, I got an error inside func_foo, stating that 'cb' is not a callback function. The above code worked fine on the first EC2 instance (linux based) and a dedicated Win7 based Node/Mongo machine. After digging some more, I've discovered, that for some reason, db.colleciton.remove, returns 2 arguments, instead of 1, as it does on the other machines, so now, 'cb' is the 2nd argument, which is not a function; thus the error.

I can always modify the function(result,cb) to function(result1, result2, cb) type code and then check inside to see if result2 is a function, and if so, use that as a callback. But I am concerned that I might have similar issues at other places, and I really don't want to change the code that is working on other machines.

So, my first question is: are there any flags/enables to mongo, at startup time, that might result in different behavior of the db.collection.remove() call. I am using the following command to start the mongo daemon: 'sudo /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf'. I don't remember how I started it on the first EC2 instance (it was over 6 month ago). But mongod.conf files are identical on both instances, since the 2nd instance is replicated copy of the 1st instance.

The 2nd question is more general: what is the best way of dealing with functions that sometimes return one argument and sometimes two. I've run across this phenomena with MongoDB NodeJS driver. And how can one tell how many arguments the function will return, other than looking at the source code. The documentation only mentions one argument.

Thank you,
Gary

Answer (score 0):

After digging through the NodeJS Mongo driver and Mongo online documentation, I found what the problem is and want to share this with others.

There is a change in how Mongo handles insert/update/delete operations going from version 2.4.x to 2.6.x. On my original EC instance, I've been running the 2.4.x version, the new instance was updated to 2.6.x version.

In 2.4.x version, the delete command, for example, would return the number of items deleted. If the user wanted to check for errors, getLastError command could be called. In 2.6.x version, the delete command returns the number of items deleted AND the output of the getLastError command. The net effect is that now the delete command returns 2 values, as opposed to just one in ver 2.4.x

My original EC2 instance had Mongo updated to 2.6.x, but the server has not been restarted, so it was still running 2.4.x.

I now need to decide if I should simply load 2.4.x version or rewrite my code to support the new requirements of 2.6.x.